# Print function names from crash information

Tags: linux, debugging, stack, dump, dmd

My program (which is compiled with DMD, a D compiler, on Linux) is crashing, and printing information like:

```
./program() [0x807aff8]
./program() [0x807aea9]
```

How can I convert the addresses of the functions to its names? I've compiled my program with the `-debug` and `-g` so it should include the required debugging information, I just don't know how to use it.

(PS: This is something simple but I can't seem to find how to do it. Probably not using the right search terms).

Comment: run the program with gdb, check the stack. also `man addr2line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `addr2line` utility

```
$ gcc -g s.c
$ addr2line 0x400855    
s.c:42
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your aplication inside gdb, then, after the crash, type bt to print the complete backtrace, which usually much better than just the line where the crash happened.

Comment: After I type `bt` I get "No stack.". I suspect this is because the crash is from an unhandled exception instead of segfault... is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Maybe something is messing the stack. Try running it through valgrind